# Acceso los valores en una lista de diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, soy super nueva en esto y me estoy pegando con las listas de diccionarios.

Tengo una lista formada por diccionarios, en la que dichos diccionarios, tienen como valores, a su vez, una lista. Ejemplo:

`lista=[{‘Pepe’: [‘Verde’, ‘Rojo’]}, {‘Juan’: [‘Verde’, 'Negro', 'Amarillo']}, {‘Paco’: [‘Azul', 'Rojo']}]`

Necesito consultar si 'Azul' se encuentra entre los valores de la lista del diccionario con clave ‘Pepe’. Y si no está, añadirlo.

¡Muchísimas gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: Para obtener ayuda primero debes publicar el código que has escrito hasta el momento. Edita tu pregunta para incluirlo (como texto, no como imagen).

Comment: Itera por la lista. Para cada `elemento` de ella, puedes mirar con un if si `"Pepe" in elemento`. En ese caso puedes acceder a `elemento["Pepe"]` para obtener la lista `l` de colores, y luego mirar si `"Azul" in l`, y si no está `l.append("Azul")`. Deliberadamente no te doy el código sino solo las ideas, para que lo intentes por ti misma, que es la forma de aprender.

Answer (score 0):

Hola esta seria mi forma de hacerlo, espero te sea de utilidad

```
for nombres in lista:
    for nombre in nombres:
        if (nombre == 'Pepe'):
            if ('Azul' not in nombres[nombre]):
                nombres[nombre].append('Azul')
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una explicación se agradecería bastante :)

Comment: Antes de responder, es mejor esperar a que el usuario demuestre que ha intentado resolver su problema (_no hacemos la tarea de los demas_). A partir de su código es cuando se aconseja formular una respuesta. **PD** sin explicación no se puede aprender. _"Dale a un hombre un pez y comerá un día; enséñale a pescar y comerá siempre"_